# Looping through subsetted objects and storing output in R

Tags: r, string, for-loop, subset

I have 10 objects named `output_ens1` through `output_ens10`. I would like to take one piece of data from each, perform arithmetic on it, and add it to a new object. I have been trying with a for loop and subsetting. Here is an example object with my loop

```
## Values used elsewhere in model output processing
num_sp <- 46  # Enter the number of species modeled
num_steps <- 36 # Enter the number of months modeled
num_ens <- 10 # Enter the number of runs in the ensemble

## example object of same dimensions
output_ens1 <- matrix(data = c(1:11880), ncol = 330, nrow = 36)

hist <- c(1:num_ens)
for (i in hist)
{
  hist[i] <- as.name(paste0("output_ens", i))[num_steps,8+num_sp*7]/1000
}
```

This returns

```
Error in as.name(paste0("output_ens", i))[num_steps, 8 + num_sp * 7] : 
  object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

I would like the num_steps (36th) row, and the 8+num_sp*7 (330th) column value divided by 1000 and added to object `hist`. In this example, the value 11.88 (11880/1000) would be set as `hist[1]`.I have tried several iterations, and believe my issue is with reading the name of the objects in to be subset. What direction should I be heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead:

```
get(paste0("output_ens", i))
```

Comment: wow. Of everything i tried, i skipped "get"... Thanks!